# How to debug WCF-Service with UserName Authentication?

Tags: wcf, debugging, authentication, wcftestclient

theoretically, I can debug a WCF-service with Microsofts WCF-Testclient. Practically am I using UserName Authentication and the TestClient doesn't have the possibility to pass the User Credentials. Is there any workaround or maybe other debugging tool? How do you debug your secure WCFs?
I especially love the functionality to be able to step into the code of the WCF.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SOAPUI from soapui.org.  Great tool for testing, you won't be able to step through your code, but you can at least get relevant error messages.  The free version should allow you to do whatever you want.  I like it because you can save your tests and have multiple tests for each method.

Comment: there's no way to attach to process and step through code using soapui?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  I only use the free version.  We have an identitical development environment and I have as of yet to be unable to replicate an issue within this environment and simply debug using VS.